# Question on why Lee chooses to define the standard smooth structure on a f.d. vector space in a certain way

Tags: definition, smooth-manifolds

In Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, Lee defines the **standard smooth structure of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$** to be the smooth structure induced by the collection of charts $$\{(V,E^{-1}) : E : \mathbf{R}^n \to V \text{ is a basis coefficient assignment function}\}$$

That is, one chart for each choice of basis of $V$. He further shows that these charts are smoothly compatible; i.e., the transition function $\tilde{E} \circ E^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism of $\mathbf{R}^n$.

---

Here is my question: why did he go to the effort of showing that this collection of charts are smoothly compatible? Is it not sufficient to observe that for a chosen basis $(E_1,\dots,E_n)$ of $V$, the basis coefficient assignment function $E(\mathbf{x}) = \sum x^iE_i$ is a diffeomorphism, hence $(V,E^{-1})$ is a smooth chart, and is in fact a smooth atlas itself, contained within a smooth structure which we define as the standard smooth structure of $V$.

I may just be confusing myself here-- perhaps Lee decided that more rather than less information about the standard structure is helpful. On the other hand, I may be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not sufficient to observe that for a chosen basis $(E_1,\dots,E_n)$ of $V$, the basis coefficient assignment function $E(\mathbf{x}) = \sum x^iE_i$ is a diffeomorphism, hence $(V,E^{-1})$ is a smooth chart, and is in fact a smooth atlas itself, contained within a smooth structure which we define as the standard smooth structure of $V$.

Of course each choice of a basis $\mathcal E$ induces a smooth structure $\mathfrak S_\mathcal E$ on $V$. But there are many choices of a basis, and none of these choices has priority. Theoretically it could be possible that the $\mathfrak S_\mathcal E$ are distinct for distinct bases of $V$. Wouldn't that be a disaster?

Lee proves that all bases $\mathcal E$ induce **the same** smooth structure on $V$, that is, the choice of $\mathcal E$ is irrelevant. In other words, $V$ has a canonical smooth structure. With this smooth structure **all** linear isomorphisms $\phi : \mathbb R^n \to V$ become diffeomorphisms which is not a priori obvious.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!